# How do I restore a registry from a .hiv file in powershell?

Tags: powershell, registry

I have a .hiv file and I want to import it using powershell
what is the command to restore .hiv file in powershell?

Help me out as I could not find the correct command to do so

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use:

```
reg load HKLM\TempHive TempHive.hiv
```

As per [this documentations Examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-load).